# Why string cannot be converted to dateTime?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I have this string:

```
 {2018-06-17 10:05:41}
```

At some point I try to convert it to DateTime:

```
  DateTime.ParseExact(cell.StringCellValue, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

But I get this exception:

```
 "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
```

Any idea why string above not recognized as a DateTime and how to fix it?

Comment: Did you make sure the string is in the right format for the DateTime parsher?

Comment: `{2018-06-17 10:05:41}` and `dd/MM/yyyy` don't match. The format string defines where in the input string `ParseExact` looks for the date components.

Comment: the template used does not match the provided string

Comment: @Dirk dirk thanks for post!what if my string date is like that:"10:05:41 2018-06-17"?

Comment: @Michael Then you look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings to determine your format string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are using the wrong format - `2018-06-17 10:05:41` is `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` (not sure about the `HH` part, it might be `hh`, but the lack of `AM/PM` is a hint).

Also, you would be better off using [`TryParseExact`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=netframework-4.7.2) then `ParseExact`:

```
DateTime dateTime;
DateTime.TryParseExact(
    cell.StringCellValue, 
    "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
    DateTimeStyles.None, 
    out dateTime);
```

since you will not have to handle exceptions in case the parse fails.

Comment: Thanks for post!But I get error "No overload for method 'TryParseExact' takes 4 argument" on TryParseExact method.

Comment: Yes, I copied the code from the question and forgot about the `DateTimeStyles` argument. Fixed now.